# EEVEE Render issue

Tags: eevee-render-engine, visibility

Trying to do a low poly animation using EEVEE and when I did a test render of a single frame today the frame looks fine in the viewport render but the actual render is messed up with duplicate parts of the image and objects not in the right place.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Actually just tried Cycles too and get the same issue

Comment: One object (Car.003) is hidden is the viewport. Is it hidden in the render too ? (to verify, click the "funnel" icon on top of the outliner, then select the "camera" icon)

Comment: Yeah that was it :D thank you, still learning :D

Answer (score 4):

You need to click the Filter dropdown above the Collection tree and enable the **Disable in Renders** option so it's visible. Then, click it so that it's turned off on Car.003.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue, still learning :D