# Weird "thing" after rendering, can't find solution

Tags: rendering, animation

So i got this weird thing ONLY after rendering and i don't know what to do. I am new to blender and i would really appreciate any help. I dont know if its some kind of shade or something. I've sent two after and before screens.

[image: after rendering1]
[image]

[image: after rendering2]
[image: before rendering]

Comment: Hello :). This looks like a triangle that's only hidden in viewport but allowed in render.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EEVEE Render issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168158/eevee-render-issue)